# Closure Compiler failing to compile reserved word "default"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, google-closure-compiler, javascript-import

I'm using Babel (actually Babelify) and Google Closure Compiler.

Babel transforms the following line of code:

```
import `React` from 'react'
React.createClass(...);
```

to something like

```
var _react = require(402);
var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);
_react2.default.createClass(...);
```

The problem is that Closure Compiler doesn't like the `.default` literal, and omits the following warning:

> WARNING - Keywords and reserved words are not allowed as unquoted property names in older versions of JavaScript. If you are targeting
>   newer versions of JavaScript, set the appropriate language_in option.
>   exports.default = {

I tried using the babel es3 plugins such as [transform-es3-member-expression-literals](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es3-member-expression-literals/), but they don't seem to work, probably because the problematic code is generated by another plugin.

Is there a way to solve this without telling Closure Compiler to ignore this warning? (I want ES3 support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message tells you exactly - set the `--language_in` (and optionally the `--language_out`) flags.

The latest version of the compiler, v20151216, now defaults to ES6 as the input language (ES3 as the output).

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought that settings `language_in` will also produce es6 code.

Comment: I just upgraded to the latest version of Closure Compiler and the problem was solved.